# How to prepare django app for deploying on server?

Tags: django

I followed a tutorial from a site and I  deployed my django app on pythonanywhere.com.For this purpose I had to use git to upload codes.As a result my settings.py file was accessible by anybody.so any one could see my secret key on settings.py .It is not good right?
I also left DEBUG = True later I found it is not secure.Then I set DEBUG = False on my local machine and it showed it need allowed hosts.What are those things? what should I do?  Where can I learn about these?

Comment: What do you mean with make it accessible by anyone. Git does not make your files accessible by anyone. It will be accessible if you push the commits for example to GitHub.

Comment: Actually I didn't use git before I just followed the tutorial.And I found that I can see the codes of my project even if I am not signed in.

Comment: See them where?

Comment: I can see them on github

Comment: I just made a simple app just to learn deploying.Here is the link,you will be also able to see my codes:https://github.com/kamrulhasan0/my-first-app

Comment: OK but there was no need for you to put the code on GitHub; that has nothing to do with deployment. But if you do want to put it there, note that GitHub now provide free private repositories.

Comment: I followed several tutorials and at first they put code on github and then put those on server.Ok then I have to find another way.Thank you.